# Recursive Main function

Tags: c, recursion

I have to make the code of a coffee dispenser in C.

I already have everything done and I just need to know how I can keep on running my "main" function until a certain condition is met (for example: util the machine can give no more change).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "recursive main"!  You *may* call a recursive function from main().  You may *not* make "main()" itself recursive!  It sounds like maybe all you want is a loop in "main()"!

Comment: @paulsm4 Of course you can call `main()` from inside `main()`, although it's really bad practice

Comment: Why not a `loop`? ex: `while (condition_met) {blah blah}`

Comment: @paulsm4 — actually, in C, it is legitimate if unorthodox to call `main()` recursively.  It is not a good idea, even in C, and C++ definitively disallows it.  I believe the OP is looking for a loop in the `main()` function, which might well call another function.  Recursion is probably not the answer — you have to know how and when the recursion will unwind, especially in a machine such as a coffee dispenser which probably doesn't have gigabytes of main memory.

Comment: C allows calling of the `main` function, but it's a really bad habit. Use loops instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need a recursive main or for that matter any recursive function call at all for this. All you need is an infinite loop.

```
int main()
{
    while (1) /* Infinite Loop */
    {
        ... do stuff 
        
        if (condition is met)
            break;
    }
}
```